# Button padding modified on icon added to materialize dropdown

Tags: css, padding, materialize

I am using a materialize [dropdown](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html).
Without any icon the button looks ok, however if I add an icon like this:

```
{/* <!-- Dropdown Trigger --> */}
<a className='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#!' data-target='dropdown1'>Type<i className="large material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
```

The padding gets affected and the text goes down, see picture:

[image]

What would be the way to solve this? On the other hand is there any way to see or get materialize code into a project to check the code and check what the css classes do, so as to correct small issues like this or extend some?
By the way, I am using react.

Thanks

Edit: What I tried:

```
<div className="row" style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
    <a className='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#!' data-target='dropdown1'>Type<i className="large material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using material `row` and `col`? Use `row` under the tag `a`, set the style `align-items: center`, then put the other two in col.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I dont understand you very well. I need the `dropdown-trigger btn` class in tag `a` for the dropdown to work. You mean inserting `div`s?

Comment: Yes. Inserting `div`s

Comment: I edited what you suggested. See updated answer with inlined react styling. It did not work. Thanks a lot for the suggestion anyhow

Comment: I will try to elaborate my previous explanation in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the materalize helper `valign-wrapper` div under the `a` tag like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 
   <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#!' data-target='dropdown1'>
     <div class="valign-wrapper">
       Type<i class="large material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
     </div>
   </a>
```

In your case, the your code should be:

```html
<a className='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#!' data-target='dropdown1'>
    <div className="row" style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
        Type<i className="large material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </div>
</a>
```